# How to enable VSFTPD only for specified ips?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I use VSFTPD (ubuntu server) do manage files on my dedicated server. For security reasons, I'd like to allow to connect use FTP **only for couple specified ips**. Is it possible to do? I was googling, but I haven't found anything that could help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google how to use IP tables. You can use the firewall to only allow connections on that port for specific IP's; your FTP server won't have anything to do with blocking them and your firewall will handle the work it's best suited to do.